# Mercator map projection logic conflict

Tags: c, math, map-projections, mercator

I'm looking for an explanation on why there are 2 different mercator formulas discussed on these sites.

I understand this to be the correct mercator projection algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection

```
y = ln|sec(lat) + tan(lat)|
```

However, this site refers to something completely different:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator

```
#include <math.h>
double lat2y(double a) { return 180/M_PI * log(tan(M_PI/4+a*(M_PI/180)/2)); }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both formulas are equal.

- > sec(x) + tan(x) = **[ 1 + sin(x) ] / cos(x)**

  [image: sec(x) + tan(x) = [ 1 + sin(x) ] / cos(x)]
- > tan(pi/4 + x/2) = sin(pi/4 + x/2) / cos(pi/4 + x/2) =
  >
  > = [cos(x/2) + sin(x/2)] / [cos(x/2) - sin(x/2)] =
  >
  > = [cos(x/2) + sin(x/2)]^2 / [cos(x/2) - sin(x/2)] / [cos(x/2) + sin(x/2)] =
  >
  > = [1 + 2*cos(x/2)*sin(x/2)] / [cos^2(x/2) - sin^2(x/2)] =
  >
  > = **[1 + sin(x)] / cos(x)**

  [image]

The latter formula is more convenient for numerical calculations, because it involves the computation of the trigonometric function only once.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the derivation - helped me a lot. In turn I've beautified your answer a bit. Hope you don't mind.